# SCAN function to change a phrase

Tags: sas

I have a decode phrase (AE_SER_D) 'Is a significant medical event in the Investigator's judgment” that I need to change to ‘Is a significant medical event in the Investigators judgment’ as the apostrophe between r and s is causing the program to error out. I can't change the decode (AE_SER_C) but wanted to program a line of code using a scan function to search if ae_ser_d is ne '' and contains this phrase but only want to search for a partial segment of the phrase as If I search for the whole phrase it will cause the program to still error out because of the apostrophe. Is SCAN the best option here?.

Comment: COMPRESS() may be a better option as it can remove the ' directly without worrying about the location or if there's multiple reasons for the apostrophe.

Comment: Just having single quotes (aka apostrophe) in the value of a variable should not cause any coding issue.  Show what code you are running where the single quote is causing trouble.  Note if you want to write that value as a literal value you will either need to use double quotes on the outside or double the single quote. `'don''t'` or `"don't"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with Reeza's idea: Remove all punctuation marks with the `compress()` function and the `'p'` option. Assuming you want a single quote around the whole phrase, enclose the result with single quotations using `cats()`.

```
data want;
    AE_SER_D = cat("'Is a significant medical event in the Investigator's ", 'judgment"');
    AE_SER_D_Fixed = cats("'", compress(AE_SER_D,,'p'), "'");
run;
```

If you only need to remove quotations and need to keep other punctuation marks, specify them directly in `compress()`:

```
data want;
    AE_SER_D = cat("'Is a significant medical event in the Investigator's ", 'judgment"');
    AE_SER_D_Fixed = cats("'", compress(AE_SER_D, "'"""), "'");
run;
```

Source: [KevinQin](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/compress-single-and-double-quote/m-p/63399/highlight/true#M18022)